# disabling log4j not working after changing project to spring boot

Tags: java, log4j2

We have always been able to disable logging from our Unit Test via this line

```
Logger.getLogger(ServiceImpl.class).setLevel(Level.OFF);
```

However after changing the project to spring boot this no longer works.  Logs are written when unit test is ran.
I have also tried adding a log4j2.xml in our test/resources and set the root level to off, but this had no effect either.
How can I disable console output when unit testing?

Comment: What version of Log4j and Spring Boot are you using? `Logger.getLogger` is not Log4j 2.x. If you are using the standard `spring-boot-starter-logging`, it does not use Log4j, but Logback. Everything except Logback's configuration is ignored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as the comment above mentions, logback is  being used

created a logback-test file and set root level to off and this resolved the issue

```
  <configuration>
  <statusListener class="ch.qos.logback.core.status.NopStatusListener" />
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
            <Pattern>
                %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n
            </Pattern>
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <root level="off">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </root>

</configuration>
```